# The "Message" task was not found

Tags: .net, msbuild

Suddenly when I opened by Visual Studio 2008 solution today and tried to rebuild all, I got the following error:

> The "Message" task was not found.
>   Check the following: 1.) The name of
>   the task in the project file is the
>   same as the name of the task class.
>   2.) The task class is "public" and implements the
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask
>   interface. 3.) The task is correctly
>   declared with  in the
>   project file, or in the *.tasks files
>   located in the
>   "D:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"
>   directory

I don't understand anything of this. Can you please guide.

Comment: There should be configuration properties of visual studio, you can check the checkbox next the project you build. Maybe this can help

Comment: They are MsBuild errors, something is wrong in a .SLN or .CSPROJ file.

Comment: I've found that just cleaning the solution/project and then rebuilding makes it go away. Still... sucks though.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I restarted my computer and the error disappeared :)

**Updated:**

Based on the below comments (Thanks to @Thomas & @Vikram), it seems that restarting Visual Studio also fixes the issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. And the error disappeared after a reboot. I am using VS 2010 - SP1. This is for sure a bug!

Comment: yup Restarting VS 2012 solves the issue. Appreciate you posting this .

Comment: VS 2013 Community restart allowed project to run, but Error still exists.

Comment: You can try restarting computer (like I mentioned above)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in VS 2013 and fixed it by cleaning the solution.

Comment: I didn't try clean, but I did try rebuild.  The rebuild worked and a few (update) builds after that worked too.  Then a build failed with the same error as in the question.  Restarting VS eliminated the error more permanently ... until the next time this mysterious error happens :)

Comment: Clean was not sufficient for me, restarting VS "resolved" the apparent issue.

Comment: I even deleted and re-created the project from scratch.  Still saw the same problem.  It seems like once the msbuild includes are screwed up, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the offending project and select "Clean". It's a bit faster than restarting VS. I still don't know what is causing this issue for me but that fixes it so that I can build the project.

Comment: worked fine.  When I switched to a different branch I had the same problem and had to repeat.  Need to find out why today is different to yesterday.

Comment: I suspect there is more going on behind the scenes here than I have had the time to try and figure out. As a result, the "Clean" solution might work for some and not others. It's certainly worth a try though, as it's generally quick and harmless.